# Outlook Find/Restrict with contain

Tags: c#, outlook

is there anyway I can use Find or Restrict with something like outlookfield.contains(mystring)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.restrict%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Can you put some more detail in this question? I have no idea what you want to do or why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify fields in squared brackets like shown in the following snippets:

```
Set contact = objContacts.Items.Find("[Email1Address]=" & Chr(34) & .SenderEmailAddress & Chr(34))

Set contact = objContacts.Items.Find("[FileAs] = ""Smith, Jeff"" and [FirstName] = ""Jeff""")
```

The fieldnames are described in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220093%28v=office.11%29.aspx) or can be inspected using the VBA object catalog viewer.

To implement `Contains`, you can use `*` as wildcard before and after the string you are looking for (eg "*myString*"). To search the field for a literal `*`, you have to use `~*`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation you linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._items.restrict%28v=office.14%29.aspx), no there is no way to do it.

> **Additional Notes**
>
> If you are trying to use the Find or Restrict methods with
>   user-defined fields, the fields must be defined in the folder,
>   otherwise an error will occur. There is no way to perform a "contains"
>   operation. For example, you cannot use Find or Restrict to search for
>   items that have a particular word in the Subject field. Instead, you
>   can use the AdvancedSearch method, or you can loop through all of the
>   items in the folder and use the InStr function to perform a search
>   within a field. You can use the Restrict method to search for items
>   that begin within a certain range of characters. For example, to
>   search for all contacts with a last name beginning with the letter M,
>   use this filter:
>
> sFilter = "[LastName] > 'LZZZ' And [LastName] < 'N'"

It isn't clear from your question exactly what you are trying to do so to give some more context I am trying to count all the emails that have a subject containing a certain string (I've called it mystring to match your example).

Here is the code I started with:

```
 string mystring = "Such String";
 int count = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = " + mystring).Count;
 Debug.WriteLine("{0} email(s) contain '{1}'", count, mystring);
```

This would work so long as the subject of the email was an **exact** match to mystring which isn't good enough, I needed it to count if the string was contained anywhere in the subject.

I tried [Axel Kemper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15226250/971299) of adding * symbols as a wildcard but it didn't work for me.

Rather than use the AdvancedSeach method (its rather cryptic documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.advancedsearch(v=office.14).aspx)) I opted to perform a loop through each item and check manually if it contained the string of interest:

```
string mystring = "Such String";
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in inboxFolder.Items)
{
    if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
         Outlook.MailItem mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
         if (mailItem.Subject != null && mailItem.Subject.Contains(mystring))
         {
             count++;
         }
    }
}
Debug.WriteLine("{0} email(s) contain '{1}'", count, mystring);
```

I've left the code unrefactored to ease readability and understanding but this can also be made into a one liner LINQ expression:

```
string mystring = "Such String";
int count = inboxFolder.Items.OfType<Outlook.MailItem>().Count(mailItem => mailItem.Subject != null && mailItem.Subject.Contains(mystring));
Debug.WriteLine("{0} email(s) contain '{1}'", count, mystring);
```

Output from both:

> 42 email(s) contain 'Such String'